# How to mount Azure file share on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, azure-storage

Is it possible to mount Azure file share on my Ubuntu instance running on AWS EC2?

Comment: You need select Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, considering you meet the requirements:

> In order to mount an Azure File share outside of the Azure region it
>   is hosted in, such as on-premises or in a different Azure region, the
>   OS must support the encryption functionality of SMB 3.0. Encryption
>   feature for SMB 3.0 for Linux was introduced in 4.11 kernel. This
>   feature enables mounting of Azure File share from on-premises or a
>   different Azure region. At the time of publishing, this functionality
>   has been backported to Ubuntu from 16.04 and above.

Follow this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux